# Flex: listening to customEvent from parentApplication

Tags: apache-flex, event-handling, popup

I am trying to listen to an event created in a spark popup tileWindow. The aim is to get an array sent and updated in the popUp, to be received by the calling application, when the popUp is closed.

As commented inline below, I have tested that it reaches the point of dispatching event in the popUp- and never gets listened in main application. What am i missing?

My customEvent is as follows:

```
package folder1
{           
import flash.events.Event;
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

public class MyCustomEvent extends Event
{
    public var myDataToPass:ArrayCollection;
    public static const ON_SUBMIT:String = "submit";

    public function MyCustomEvent (type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
 }
}
```

In the PopUp, within tileWindow I have

```
public var newEvent:MyCustomEvent=new MyCustomEvent("submit");
        private function closePopUp():void{

            newEvent.myDataToPass=elementData;
            dispatchEvent(newEvent);
            trace(" came into close function"); //this is tested
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

        }
```

Finally in the calling application I have this structure

```
private function createModifyPopUp(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            var modify:Modify=new Modify();
            modify.elementData=elements;
            modify.eventTarget=evt.currentTarget;
            addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuild);

            trace("came  into modify"); //this is tested
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(modify,this,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modify);
        }



        private function rebuild(evt:MyCustomEvent):void{
            trace("got listened");//NEVER REACHES HERE
            elements=evt.myDataToPass;
            buildfunction(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the parent container of pop ups in Flex is not an `Application` or visual component which creates pop up but `SystemManager`. So if you want to use event bubbling from your pop-up window you should listen to events of `SystemManager` instance which is available through component's `systemManager` property.

As for myself I prefer not to use bubbling in such cases but subscribe to pop-up window events directly getting link to the window in `addPopUp` method.

Comment: I tried with modify.systemManager.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuildCircuit);   I get a TypeError: Error #1009 "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Not sure- modify has been instantiated; is there something separate for systemManager

Comment: if the above is not recomended, how would you suggest I subscribe to events via the PopUp method?

Comment: What is `modify`? Is it visual component? And why not to subscribe to your `Modify`'s event directly? And if you want to have compatibility with your current code just use `systemManager.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuild);` instead of `addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuild);`

Comment: THe recommended way is to dispatch non-bubbling events from your `Modify` component and subscribe to this event to `modify` instance directly: `modify.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuild);`

Comment: modify is my PopUp spark titlewindow.. tried with suggestion: systemManager.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuild);- event doesn't get listened on execution.                                       What other way is available for me to listed to a custom event getting created in the titleWindow- (and also getting the updated array-myDataToPass)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private function createModifyPopUp(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            var modify:Modify=new Modify();
            modify.elementData=elements;
            modify.eventTarget=evt.currentTarget;
            modify.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.ON_SUBMIT,rebuild);

            trace("came  into modify"); //this is tested
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(modify,this,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modify);
        }
```

You can find a more elaborate example for the solution of your problem here: http://xposuredesign.net/?p=53

Cheers

Comment: tried this- didn't help at all- probably something to do with what Constantiner above said...